# How to set up an Azure DevOps service connection or endpoint to my localhost Jenkins install

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins installed on an Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS desktop PC on my localhost.

I also have an AzureDevOps repo on which I can successfully run a build, through a Jenkins pipeline job, connecitivity achieved via my AzureDevOps personal access token (PAT).

I am now trying to set up a Jenkins service connection or endpoint in AzureDevOps, to enable me trigger an Azure DevOps pipeline release whenever a Jenkins build completes successfully.

To achieve this in AzureDevOps, I am trying to set up access to Jenkins via a Jenkins service endpoint. The endpoint configuration requires among others, a Jenkins "Server URL" (screenshot below). Not surprisingly, AzureDevOps is unable to connect to my Jenkins instance as it's running on my local machine and therefore not publicly accessible.

Any suggestions on how I can overcome this hurdle would be most appreciated.[image]

Comment: You probably need to configure the agent job

Comment: Nothing new to report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set up an Azure DevOps service connection or endpoint to my localhost Jenkins install

As we know, in order to receive the service hook notifications, you'll need to expose a port to the public internet.

To expose a port to the public internet, you can try to use the tool [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/product):

> ngrok exposes local servers behind NATs and firewalls to the public
>   internet over secure tunnels.

Please check the document [Configure a service hook for PR events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server?view=azure-devops#configure-a-service-hook-for-pr-events) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how configuring the Agent job would be the answer to this issue as proposed by @Dillip Kumar Behera. I do however intend to try Ngrok as suggested by Leo Liu or use one of the free DNS services out there to make the Jenkins URL publicly assessible.